# Can't decide which drive to choose to install Ubuntu Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive

This is my first time trying to install Ubuntu on my PC. I am using Windows 10.
I have two identical NVME SSDs installed (both 1 TB - Western Digital), one of them is newly installed and completely empty.

I downloaded the Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS and made bootable flash drive. Everything is good until I reach Installation type window.
Now, I have three options. I would like to keep Windows and install Ubuntu on the 2nd Hard Disk, so the operating systems don't share a drive. When I click on 'something else' type installation I get so many different volumes and I am so confused which one to choose.

[image]
[image]
[image]

The only difference I see is nvme0n1 and nvme1n1. Which one exactly should I choose? And I don't want to have a lot of weird partitions. Two simple Drives for each operating system.

If I click 'Erase disk and Install Ubuntu' I see this.

[image]

That would mean it will erase the content if I click on the one I already have windows on. I have no way of telling which one's the right one.

So! for now I quit the installation and looking for an advice. I am sorry if this is a long post and also if this is a stupid question. I would really appreciate if someone could help me and solve this mystery for me.

Comment: With two drives, you really need to use Something Else. And need to know partitions. You should have Windows in UEFI boot mode, but I do not see that with what you have posted so far. Post this from live installer in live mode: `sudo parted -l` What brand/model system? What video card/chip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I would suggest:

- **BACKUP ANY IMPORTANT DATA, JUST TO BE ON THE SAFE SIDE**

0. **Make note of which nvme drive is in *exactly* which slot on your motherboard**
1. Remove the recently installed nvme drive from your computer *(make sure you can boot into Windows, to be sure you removed the correct drive)*
2. With the newly added drive removed, reboot the computer into the Ubuntu live USB
3. Make your way through the installer until you reach the `Something else` option *(same section as, for example, `Erase disk and install Ubuntu`)*
4. With `Something else` selected, click `Continue`
5. When you reach the partitioning screen, make note of the name of the nvme drive listed towards the top *(either `nvme0n1` or `nvme1n1`)*, This will be the drive Windows is installed on, and should retain it's drive name even after replacing the second nvme drive *(take a picture of the partition layout just to be on the safe side)*
6. Power down your computer, reinstall the second nvme drive, and once again boot into the Ubuntu live USB
7. Repeat steps `3` and `4`, although this time with the intention of installing Ubuntu
8. Double check that the drive you noted from before *(i.e. nvme1n1)* still has the same drive layout *(that you took a picture of)*
9. Once you are as sure as you can be, click `Back` and install Ubuntu however you intend to, on your secondary nvme drive *(i.e. nvme0n1)*
10. Grab a cup of, I dunno, tea? and let the installer do it's thing
11. Reboot your computer
12. Enjoy using Ubuntu!
13. Check out OMG! Ubuntu's [10 Things to do After Installing Ubuntu 20.04 LTS](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2020/04/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu)  article for some tips and ideas

Answer (score 0):

### Install Ubuntu on Second Drive

**You can't mess up Windows drive if it is not plugged in.**

- Remove Windows drive.
- Plug in new drive.
- Boot Live USB in same mode as Windows uses, (Legacy or UEFI).
- Install Ubuntu.
- Shut down, remove Live USB, plug in Windows drive.
- Boot new Ubuntu drive and in Terminal run `sudo update-grub` to add Windows to Ubuntu's boot menu.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find out in Windows disk manager which drive had windows installed and which one had unallocated space. So in my case nvme1n1 had windows installed and nvme0n1. I realised this after @eastingNerd's answer. Thank you so much.

After I was sure in which drive I could install Ubuntu. I followed the steps and it's running perfectly fine. I think I like the User interface and after a couple of days/weeks/months hopefully I'd get used to it.