# Dual-boot 2 OS in different HDDs on the same PC

Tags: dual-boot

I have a PC with Windows 10 Pre-installed. I want to install Ubuntu on a differnt drive, but I want to still be able to boot on both on startup. Can someone explain me how to do it? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Try checking out this question thread here:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333743/cant-decide-which-drive-to-choose-to-install-ubuntu-ubuntu-20-04-2-0-lts Might find what you're looking for there

Comment: Determine if Windows boots Legacy or UEFI. Unplug Windows disk and install Ubuntu to it's own disk, in the same mode Windows boots in. Plug in Windows disk, boot Ubuntu disk and in Terminal run sudo `update-grub` to add Windows to Ubuntu's boot menu. Set Ubuntu to boot first.

Comment: If Windows 10 installed by vendor, it will be UEFI. If you have partitions on HDD you want to keep, best to partition in advance. If shrinking NTFS partitions only use Windows tools, reboot & run chkdsk, before disconnecting Windows drive. Some UEFI allow "disable" in UEFI settings for a drive, so you do not have to physically disconnect. Second drive 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296065/dual-booting-w10-ubuntu-with-2-separate-ssds-in-uefi-mode/1296153#1296153 & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/1056079#1056079

Comment: @C.S.Cameron So if I understood correct I install Ubuntu normally on a seperate disk and then I plug both disks  and run ```sudo update-grub``` ?

Comment: Yes, then if you set the Ubuntu disk to boot first, you can boot either OS from Ubuntu's GRUB. The most important part is if Windows is UEFI, install Ubuntu as UEFI. If Windows is Legacy, install Ubuntu as Legacy. Oldfred's link has some good advice also.